# Which part of my code is causing this error: Discrete Value supplied to continuous scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

My goal is to create a plot with three rectangles that represent confidence ranges, with each data point on the x-axis (independent variable) having its own label. Here is my initial code:

`plot1 <- ggplot(data = dataframe, aes(x = "Ind_variable", y = "Dep_variable"))`

Then I ran this code:

```
+ geom_rect(aes(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = 0.052, ymax = 0.20), alpha = 0.3, fill = "grey80")
+ geom_rect(aes(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = 0.071, ymax = 0.19), alpha = 0.3, fill = "grey70")
+ geom_point(shape=1) + theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

I thought it may be helpful to include the first few lines from my dataframe as well:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Ind_variable Dep_variable
  <chr>         <dbl>
1 variable_7       0.273  
2 variable_10      0.0109 
3 variable_12      0.0602 
4 variable_13     -0.00676
5 variable_21      0.0178 
6 variable_24      0.174
```

Comment: You shouldn't quote variables in the `aes()` function, you can use symbols directly as if the data was the environment: e.g. `aes(Ind_variable, Dep_variable)`. It is now interpreted as two length 1 characters.

Comment: the problem is that you set up a plot where the x-axis takes non numerical values (like `variable_7`). Afterwards you want to add a rectangle by specifying numerical x-limits which contradict the initiation of your plot